# How do I see the total used memory for a App Service Plan in Azure?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I can only find the metric for memory percentage for the app service plan, but I would like to be able to see the memory usage in MB, preferably as a breakdown per service, is this possible?

At the moment I can see that each instance I have running uses approx ~800 MB of memory, but when I combine that it does not match the memory percentage I can see for the App Service Plan.

I run two instances for my production slot and then I have one staging slot, so I thought that would be 800 x 3 = 2,400 MB, which is ~68% of the 3,5 GB I have available in my App Service Plan. The graphs shows 50-60% memory usage and when I scale out from 2 to 3 instances I can't see any major increases in memory usage in the App Service Plan, which doesn't really make any sense to me.

As I understand it the App Service Plan is the box with a given set of hardware and inside this I can scale out my app or add services until I reach the limit of that plan in memory and computing power.
If I instead would scale up I would get more memory and computing power, but maybe I have misunderstood how it all fits together?

Here you can see the memory usage before and after scaling out to a third instance.

[image: Before-After]
[image: All instances]